# jquery mobile single page size cap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I using phonegap with jquery, jquery mobile min and a custom page swipe code to build an app.  It is basically one main menu, leading to ten sub-menus, leading to approx 200 static html pages.

I combined it all into one single page so that it didn't have to reload the scripts every page change.  This worked initially, but as I continued to add to the page, after a certain point in the page none of the links work, nothing happens when they are clicked.

I'm confident it's not a problem with the html for those links, every link after that point fails.  If I cut/paste the link to the start of the doc it works fine, but then the next in line after it's original position no longer works.

At the point it stopped, the page was approx 250kb in size and 3500 lines of code.

I temporarily fixed it by creating 10 single pages, one for each submenu, which does work, but introduces it's own problems that I want to avoid if I can.

Do phonegap, jquery, or jquery mobile min have caps on how large a single page can be before they start to ignore the remainder of the code?  And is there anything I can do to get around this?

This is the custom scrolling script I am using:

```
function navnext( next ) {
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", next, {
        transition: "none"
    });
}
function navprev( prev ) {
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", prev, {
        transition: "none",
        reverse: true
    });
}


$( document ).one( "pagecreate", "#page1", function() {
    // Handler for navigating to the next page
    // Navigate to the next page on swipeleft
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
        // Get the filename of the next page. We stored that in the data-next
        // attribute in the original markup.
        var next = $( this ).jqmData( "next" );
        if ( next ) {
            navnext( next );
        }
    });
    // The same for the navigating to the previous page
    $( document ).on( "swiperight", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
        var prev = $( this ).jqmData( "prev" );
        if (prev) {
            navprev( prev );
        }
    });
});
```

And this is what the html looks like:

```
<i></i><!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jqueryswipegrey.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/deck.css"></link>
</head>
<body>


<div class="title"><h1>&nbsp;App Title</h1><a href="#page1"><img class="home" src="img/home.png"></a></div>


<!-- -------------------------------MAIN MENU-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->


<div id="page1" data-role="page" data-prev="#page1" data-next="#pagesub1"><div class="wrapper"><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"><h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                Main Menu

</h2></ul> <div data-role="content">




<font size="4">

   <p class="line"><img src="img/redline.png" width="100% of window";></p>
<p class="menu"> <a class="link" href="#pagesub1"><img class="smallcardplot" src="img/01001.jpg">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Link to First Submenu</a></p>
   <p class="line"><img src="img/redline.png" width="100% of window";></p>
```

And then:

```
<div id="pageplot" data-role="page" data-prev="#page1" data-next="#pagesubmenu2"><div class="wrapper"><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"><h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                1st Submenu

</h2></ul> <div data-role="content">

<font size="4">

<p class="line"><img src="img/redline.png" width="100% of window";></p>
<p class="menu"> <a class="link" href="#page01001"><img class="smallcardplot" src="img/01001.jpg">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;First Plot Page</a></p>
   <p class="line"><img src="img/line.png" width="100% of window";></p>
```

And then:

```
<div id="page01001" data-role="page" data-prev="" data-next="#page01002"><div class="wrapper"><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"><h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                First Content Page

</h2></ul> <div data-role="content">

                <img src="img/01001.jpg" class="plotimg">  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">


<p>A few lines of text for this page

</ul></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Just to make sure you're not overthinking it, have you run your html through the html validator?

Comment: Is that 250kb _on disk_ or 250kb served?

Comment: Ok, turns out I'm an idiot.  After spending hours fiddling with it looking for a fix, and checking and rechecking my html, it turned out that, yes I'd messed up an html tag.  Thanks Jennifer for making me go back and look again.  Sorry for wasting everyones time!

Answer (score 0):

I'd messed up an html tag.  Fixed now.